# Simple overloading error?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, string-formatting

I'm sorry if the title simple overloading error? isn't the right title. I'm not sure of the method that I've tried below...

Anyway, I want my text field to display text that I am setting here which is "Player :" then I want to call upon my variable 'string player1' and input this into the text field aswell as the text I have just set?

```
lblPDisp.Text = ("Player: {0}", Player1);
```

but it just comes up with red lines

Comment: When I started here at Stack Overflow I didn't notice there is a holo tickbox next to each answer. Ticking correct answers helps save other peoples time by knowing the issue is resolved and not to spend time troubleshooting. Ticking answers also gives you a couple of points. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close:

```
lblPDisp.Text = string.Format("Player: {0}", Player1);
```